# Modal bottom sheet with custom shape: How would you do it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is your aproach for creating this layout in Flutter as a **Widget** for **showModalBottomSheet**?

[image: image of showModalBottomSheet]

LE: Tried it with `Positioned` and `Stack` but the QR Code is still inside the modal not outside

My approach:

```
class _TicketModalState extends State<TicketModal> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(15, 0, 15, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CustomTheme.of(context).cardColor,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40),
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: -125,
                  left: 50,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: CustomTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        ),
                      child: QrImage(
                        data: "1234567890",
                        version: QrVersions.auto,
                        size: 250,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way

```
BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "MODAL BOTTOM SHEET",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: 400,
                    ),
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),

                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: const [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.close,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 430,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white70,
                                child: QrImage(
                                  data: "1234567890",
                                  version: QrVersions.auto,
                                  size: 250,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Click Me',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      letterSpacing: 0.6),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]